# Check for duplicates before processing file

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I am using SSIS to iterate through a folder and read the contents of all the txt files into a database.
Firstly I am checking to see if the file has already been processed using a stored procedure

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[CheckForDuplicateFileEntry]
(
  @TaskID INT,
  @Filename VARCHAR(50),
  @FileAlreadyExists BIT OUTPUT
)AS 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @TaskTypeID INT
    SET @FileAlreadyExists = 0

    SELECT @TaskTypeID = TaskTypeID FROM Tasks WHERE TaskID = @TaskID

    IF EXISTS ( SELECT  TaskID
                FROM    TaskSteps
                WHERE   @Filename IN (
                        SELECT TOP ( 30 )
                                TaskSteps.Filename
                        FROM    TaskSteps
                                INNER JOIN Tasks ON TaskSteps.TaskID = Tasks.TaskID
                        WHERE   ( Tasks.TaskTypeID = @TaskTypeID
                                  AND [Filename] IS NOT NULL
                                )
                                AND IsValid = 1
                                AND ProcessStatusID = 2 ) ) 
        BEGIN              
            INSERT  INTO TaskSteps ( TaskID, StepDesc )
            VALUES  (
                      @TaskID,
                      'Duplicate filename. (' + @Filename + ') Already exists.' 
                    )                
            SET @FileAlreadyExists = 1                  
        END        
END
```

I have also tried

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 30 Filename
       FROM  TaskSteps  INNER JOIN Tasks ON TaskSteps.TaskID = Tasks.TaskID
       WHERE (SUBSTRING(TaskSteps.Filename,18,13) = SUBSTRING(@Filename,18,13))
             AND IsValid = 1                            
             AND ProcessStatusID = 2)
```

But when it iterates through the files it processes the first declares the next is a duplicate processes the third and declares the fourth a duplicate and so on 
the file names are very similar ie Songs_120501_175535.txt with the filename staying the same and the date and time portion being the only part that changes and perhaps only changing by one digit ie Songs_120502_175535.txt

Answer (score 1):

This is as simple as I can get it. I would check if something else in the SSIS process or triggers etc.) is deleting or updating the TaskSteps/Task table, which is causing it to work sometimes, and other times not. Also check the `IsValid` and `ProcessStatusID` columns, as these are used in the query. Try running your query in Management Studio with the same parameters three, four, five times - and print out the `@FileAlreadyExists` value after each. If just calling the proc works correctly, then the problem is elsewhere in your SSIS.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[CheckForDuplicateFileEntry]
(
  @TaskID INT,
  @Filename VARCHAR(50),
  @FileAlreadyExists BIT OUTPUT
)AS 
BEGIN

SET @FileAlreadyExists = 0

IF EXISTS( 
           SELECT     * 
           FROM       TaskSteps
           INNER JOIN Tasks 
           ON         TaskSteps.TaskID = Tasks.TaskID
           WHERE      Tasks.TaskTypeID = TaskSteps.TaskTypeID
           AND        Tasks.TaskID = TaskSteps.TaskID
           AND        IsValid = 1
           AND        ProcessStatusID = 2
           AND        TaskSteps.Filename = @FileName
         )
    BEGIN              
        INSERT  INTO TaskSteps ( TaskID, StepDesc )
        VALUES  (
                  @TaskID,
                  'Duplicate filename. (' + @Filename + ') Already exists.' 
                )                
        SET @FileAlreadyExists = 1                  
    END        
END
```

Comment: I've assumed you want to know if the EXACT filename has been processed before. If you mean, the filename WITHOUT the date and/or time - then Asif's answer is better, maybe still without the TOP 30 though?

Comment: The top 30 part isn't making any difference Ive run it with and without it. Its only a test db so there are only a small number of rows in the table any way

Comment: Can you clarify what constitutes a FileAlreadyExists event? Is it a match on the entire FileName variable/column, or just the filename part excluding the date & time, or just the filename part excluding the time?

Comment: Is your FileName column & variable big enough to hold the entire length of the full file names?

Comment: If the txt file Songs_120626_114435.txt is being processed it looks in the filename column of the Tasks table and if it can find it, it declares it a duplicate and stops the process, otherwise it reads the contents of the file into another table in the db.

Comment: It is comparing the entire filename. and the column is a Varchar(50) so more than big enough

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13045/discussion-between-seanw-and-wellie)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Use char index function

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 30 Filename
           FROM  TaskSteps  INNER JOIN Tasks ON TaskSteps.TaskID = Tasks.TaskID
           WHERE (SUBSTRING(TaskSteps.Filename,CHARINDEX('_',TaskSteps.Filename),13) =    
                  SUBSTRING(@Filename,CHARINDEX('_',@Filename),13) ) 
                 AND IsValid = 1                            
                 AND ProcessStatusID = 2)
```

Comment: I am comparing _120502_175535 part of file. so if you want to ignore the _ character adjust the things accordingly.